# asp.net mvc handle http 400 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-400

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I want to redirect all HTTP 400 errors to my custom error page. I was searching an hours to find a solution though HTTP 400 error isn't handled like 404 error. There are many solutions that show how to escape 400(bad request error), i.e. to allow using special characters for example in url. But I  wouldn't able to find some solution to catch the exception.

Please help me to catch somehow all HTTP bad requests and redirect them to my error page.

Comment: My friend , You can Try this and be sure that it will work.. [Handle All Bad Request ( Invalid Controller / Ation ) ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570749/2574400)

Answer (score 5):

**Never redirect users in case of errors**, instead return a response body for the failed request. The feature of IIS (and ASP.NET) to redirect to an error page, I believe, is fundamentally wrong, incorrect, and against the HTTP specification (because then the error is being returned for the error page resource itself, not the original request. And if it's a web-browser the user has no way of retrying, because reloading the page will return the error page again, not retrying their original failed request, which is what they want).

Anyway...

A HTTP 400 response must be generated by your application code, it isn't something that will be done automatically. A bad request is typically used when informing non-human agents (i.e. web service clients, *not web browsers*) that their HTTP request was missing required values or had malformed values.

You can do this in MVC by having a base controller class for all of your controllers like so:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {

    protected ActionResult Http400(String message) {

        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return View(message); // you need to define a view file called "Http400.aspx" (or cshtml if you're using Razor) in your application's shared views folder
    } 

}
```

so in your application logic:

```
public ActionResult Foobar() {

    if( IsBadRequest() ) return Http400("Bad request, try again");
}
```

Comment: actually I implemented the Http400 action exactly the same way. I also define redirect the route for it in web.config in such way
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
   <error statusCode="400" redirect="HttpBadRequestError" />
</customErrors>

And also map the route for HttpBadRequestError in global.asax

routes.MapRoute(
                "HttpBadRequestError",
                "HttpBadRequestError/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Error", action = "HttpBadRequestError", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

But no result, and bad requests are showing default page.

Comment: @Gohar please don't use redirection, and the redirection feature in ASP.NET's customErrors feature does not support URL route names.

Comment: Redirection is requirement, and customErrors redirect is recognizing route name defined for 404 error without a problem

Comment: Why is it a requirement? My point is that there is no legitimate reason to perform a redirect, and in fact doing a redirect violates the HTTP specification.

Comment: Actually the requirement is to show custom error page for 404 and 400 errors. But I should create a generic mechanism for catching all errors. I can't return Http400() action in each of my controller action. How can I do it? Can you suggest me something?

Comment: A HTTP 400 error is very specific, are you thinking of 500 instead? Note that you **can** use IIS Custom Errors with static pages to display error messages, just don't use the redirect option.

Comment: I need to catch 400 errors as well. Http 500 doesn't handled bad requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as adding adding this to your web.config

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="errorpage.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I do something like it but Http 400 errors are also redirected to the route defined for http 404 errors. And I don't understand why.

Comment: would using decorating the controller action with  [HandleError] do what you need it to do?