# How to redirect all actions to one action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

i want to re-direct all actions under a controller to its index action
(one that controller, other controllers will remain default behavior)

e.g for controller "O"

```
   http://foo.com/o/abc
   http://foo.com/o
   http://foo.com/o/abc?foo=bar
```

all the above request will all go to "index" action

I tried to use below route setting, but ASP.NET complain 404 when i try to visit "http://foo.com/o/abc".

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ORoute",
                url: "o/*",
                defaults: new { controller = "O", action = "Index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try "o/" instead of "o/*"

Comment: yep.. tried. didn`t work

Comment: i am doing workaround for now. override HandleUnknownAction in controller, and force redirect to index

Comment: How about url: "o/{trash}", defaults: new { controller = "O", action = "Index", trash=""}

Answer (score 1):

First , define a controller named Error with One Action which show Customized Invalid Address page ..

Then you need to define a Class with inherit DefaultControllerFactory 
( it's name is CF)

and Then you should override its Main Method : CreateController

and finally , add this statement to global.asax which means any request should be verified by this Class.

CF Class Code:

```
public class CF : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        IController result;
        try
        {
            result = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = base.CreateController(requestContext, "Error");

        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            // Here is the Change
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CF));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "O",
    "O/{action}",
    new { controller = "O", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
);
```

The order of routes changes everything. Also, notice the changes I made to the O route. The first parameter is the name of the route. Second is the URL, which match URLs that start with O, and allows for other actions in your O controller. As you can see, it will default to the Index action.

Comment: Try this:-put redirect=true in your routes
routes.MapRoute(
    "O",
    "O/{action}",
    new { controller = "O", action = "Index",redirect = true }
);

In your O controller index action:

 public ActionResult Index(bool? redirect)
    {
        if (redirect.HasValue && redirect.Value)
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", new { redirect = null as object });
        return View();
    }